# Making api highly available in Swift Perfect

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, perfect

I have defined an API for giving data from MongoDB. But, the problem is, if I hit the api continuously from same IP address, the results are not consistent. If it gives proper result for first time, the next time it gives failed to connect. If I hit just "hello world" api, it won't fail no matter how frequently I hit from same IP. I am listening to port range of HTTP 80. Can anyone please advise me the problem and how to solve this. I'm new to this server concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, Perfect has already a high availability. Even in the most affordable VM, the api response should be still fast enough. This is my load testing result:

```
$ wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s http://localhost:19808/
Running 30s test @ http://localhost:19808/
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    30.98ms   10.10ms  86.14ms   73.83%
    Req/Sec   546.08    267.66     1.75k    58.56%
  194376 requests in 30.07s, 27.07MB read
  Socket errors: connect 157, read 717, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:   6464.58
Transfer/sec:      0.90MB
```

so even in the extremest situation, there is only 0.8% opportunity to see a bad connection. Please share us your source code otherwise no one will get the clue of what is going on your AWS instance.